# Refreshing a screen to update data in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to understand how to refresh my app screen with new data. The app is a dashboard that has several job cards and when another user applies something to the card there is a refresh button in the app that all users can press to get the latest version of the update. Stupid fix I know but I am clueless atm.... its summer and very hot any guidance will be very very appreciated.
I have a function refreshLists, within this function I have a bunch of calls to functions that send a request off to my API for data.
My problem. I am unable to understand how to send a refresh request from my asp.net 6 web API so that the screen refreshes when data has updated. My solution so far was to use an IconButton and within the on pressed it goes like this

```
onpressed() async {
 await refreshLists();
 setstate(){};
}
```

Why do I have to click the button twice for the screen to update with the new data. instead of running the function then when the lists are all updated then the screen is rebuilt.
Cheers for any help all answers will be appreciated.

=========== Update =============
Refresh List methods sends a call to my requests file to send a certain http request to my web api.

```
refreshLists() {
  getAllClients();
  getAllJobs();
  getAllJobsStatusDefined();
  getSortedJob();
}
```

Here is an example of how my request works.

```
Future getAllClients() async {
  client.badCertificateCallback =
      ((X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true);
  HttpClientRequest request =
      await client.getUrl(Uri.parse("$emulatorHost/Clients"));
  request.headers.add("Authorization", "Bearer " + jwt);

  HttpClientResponse result = await request.close();

  if (result.statusCode == 200) {
    List<dynamic> jsonData =
        jsonDecode(await result.transform(utf8.decoder).join());
    if (listCustomers.isNotEmpty) {
      listCustomers.clear();
      for (var i in jsonData) {
        listCustomers.add(
          new Customer(
            i['clientID'],
            i['clientName'],
            i['address'],
            i['phone'],
          ),
        );
      }
    } else {
      for (var i in jsonData) {
        listCustomers.add(
          new Customer(
            i['clientID'],
            i['clientName'],
            i['address'],
            i['phone'],
          ),
        );
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can see that the request method checks if the list has data if it does then it clears the list and adds all the new updated data.

Simple Example
https://github.com/Riley-Howley/FlutterRefreshHelp

Comment: For refresh the screen, you needed to clear the list in which data is assigned inside the refreshLists() function in the first line. The list will create and new data will be assigned. Try this.

Comment: Could you add code of class with API and your screen where you are trying to refresh the data?

Comment: Generally speaking, `setState` is meant to change the state and refresh the widget you are in. It's impossible to tell from your piece of code what the mistake is. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: https://github.com/Riley-Howley/FlutterRefreshHelp here is the link to minimal reproducible example cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I solved the issue.

1. I made a polling function that send a get request to my api every 5 seconds looking for the max id in the table. On first load the max ids are stored within the app and then when the id changes it does a full request of the data.
2. using a stream builder I was then able to hook up the data to refresh every 5 seconds only when the ids change and refresh the screen.
   Hope this helps anyone that is struggling.

Comment: Please how did u implement long polling in flutter

Comment: Unsure what you mean by long poling. But basically I just had a timer check every 5 seconds if the max ID in the table changed and if it did do a full get request on all the information. Using stream builders allows the screen to refresh when the poling function is done. Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

1. A simple fix to this problem is that make a stream builder and set the
   stream as your function to refresh the list.
2. Or you can use any state management so that it will notify all the
   listeners when there is a data change

Comment: Hey Thankyou for the comment! I will now implement the Stream Builder to see if it has any affect. Have a look at the github link and see what you can do if you like. Its public and ill be monitoring it all day cheers!

Comment: Sure, I will check it

Answer (score 0):

You describe 2 problems.
To trigger data update from the server, you need to establish a web-socket connection or use a 3rd party service, like firebase.

In addition, the "set state" is a basic flutter building block that you should use for specific cases. Usually, when you build an app, you would like to work with stateless widgets and a state manager that tells the UI when and what to refresh

Comment: Hey there, cheers! I don't want to use Firebase as I am using my own database and API. I will look into web sockets though.